# Converting plain password to Laravel encrypted password

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, encryption, laravel-5.4

I have a table called "users" where I have username and password from my users.

The passwords are in plain text. Now I've created a new site with Laravel 5.4 and Auth.

**So if a user wants to loggin into my site I need to convert my password plain text to the new password encrypted.**

How can I get the "salt" from my Auth and also a tools to get the encrypted password from my plain password and "salt". The reason is because I created a new column in my users table so I want to put there the password encrypted using a query.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses `bcrypt()` to hash passwords. Assuming you have the plain text passwords stored in `users.password`, you just need to loop through and `bcrpyt()` them.

```
\App\User::get()->each(function ($user) {
    $user->password = bcrypt($user->password);
    $user->save();
});
```

The above code will overwrite the plain text value stored in `users.password` with the hashed value. After you do this, user's should be able to log in with Laravel's auth. Additionally, you will not be able to retrieve the user's plain text password. This is good, and is the whole point of hashing passwords.

Comment: this solution has the advantage of overwrite plain passwords. Store plain passwords is very bad practice, I would not subscribe to any site that I know storing my password in plain